Why is the X-Gate a constant function in the deutsch-josza algorithm?
I don't understand, why the X-Gate represents a constant function.
It flips 0 to 1 and 1 to 0, which represents a balanced function.

I don't understand this explanation from my professor:


Can you give us a reference that you're getting this from? That way we can check out the context better...

i added context. is the error that the function has to be controlled?

Yes, if you want to create a balanced function, it will need to interact with the top qubit, e.g. using it as a control.

The point is that the gate, $X$, that you're applying does not depend on the top qubit. The circuit diagram makes that pretty clear because there are no connecting lines. It's that top qubit that's providing a value $x$ for the function to evaluate $f(x)$. So, if the output of $f(x)$ doesn't depend on $x$, it's a constant function.
(Remember that what you're calculating on the bottom qubit is $y\oplus f(x)$ where the bottom qubit has initial value $y$. The different values of $y$ don't relate to the function evaluation.)

what would be the simplest example for a constant function, that makes sense?

The simplest function is no gate at all. In that case, $f(0)=f(1)=0$.
